# 'Forge Design Automation v3' Keeps Running Forever

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm using Forge Design Automation v3 for Revit to export information from Revit Files on BIM360 Doc. The function keeps running forever in some files while the result is Success, the other files still fine. We have tested on the local machine but it still working with the same file on BIM360 Doc. Is this a server-side issue? Is there any work around on this?

```
[08/06/2020 05:06:47] Coordinate Information !!!
[08/06/2020 05:06:47] Saving file!!!
[08/06/2020 05:06:47] Close Document!!!
[08/06/2020 05:06:50] Cleanup !!!
[08/06/2020 05:06:50] T:\Aces\Jobs\0b982f3b9bb9480daaa6761a55570e5b\0b982f3b9bb9480daaa6761a55570e5b.log
[08/06/2020 05:06:50] T:\Aces\Jobs\0b982f3b9bb9480daaa6761a55570e5b\output.json
[08/06/2020 05:06:50] T:\Aces\Jobs\0b982f3b9bb9480daaa6761a55570e5b\params.json
[08/06/2020 05:06:50] Application Shutdown!!!
[08/06/2020 05:06:51] Finished running.  Process will return: Success
[08/06/2020 05:06:51] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[08/06/2020 05:32:08] Error: Revit Core Engine Core Console is shut down due to process time limit.
[08/06/2020 05:32:08] End script phase.
[08/06/2020 05:32:08] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[08/06/2020 05:32:08] Job finished with result FailedLimitProcessingTime
[08/06/2020 05:32:08] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedLimitProcessingTime",
  "reportUrl": "",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2020-08-06T05:02:08.1551773Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2020-08-06T05:02:08.459911Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2020-08-06T05:03:33.9567909Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2020-08-06T05:32:08.9840035Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 850197652
  },
  "id": ""
}
```

Comment: The activity works for some files, but fails for some other files, right? Looks the workitem is done at 08/06/2020 05:06:51, but the engine is still running until time out, looks an issue on the server side, we are investigating on this now.

Comment: Yes, this situation only happen on some files. The engine seems keep running forever even the OnShutdown() method is called at [08/06/2020 05:06:50]

Comment: @VietBui - Do you see this behavior consistently on those files? Is there a way to build a minimal reproducible example for this problem?

Comment: @RahulBhobe yes, this behavior consistently on those files, are there any secured way I can send the model to you to re-produce it?

Comment: Could you include details in an email to `forge.help@autodesk.com` and reference this SO post?

Comment: I will. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi @RahulBhobe, is there any update on this issue?

Comment: @VietBui, sorry for a delay. we are investigating it and will post what we get as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @EmmaZhu, thank you, its good to know its under investigation!

Comment: @VietBui, we can confirm this is a server-side issue on 2019. The revit file you provided could fail our own addin in the same way. We are still identifying the fundamental reason at this moment. I will update once we found out more.
As a workaround, you could try Design Automation V3 for Revit 2020. I tried with the revit file you provided, it succeeded on 2020. Let us know if 2020 would work for you.

Comment: Hi @EmmaZhu, I can confirm that the work-around on 2020 working. But it seems not an efficient way because it takes around 30min for just update the model from 2019 to 2020. We still looking forward to the fix on the 2019 engine if possible.

Comment: @VietBui, thank you for trying and confirming. Yes, we understand and we will see what we can do on 2019!